# angularjs how to change Appended each text value separately

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to change appended fields each label value from ng-show field label option, when we click on appended field it shows field label option. How can I change each label value from single field label option?.
[you can go here for plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoiedELDtTaBzUi6EwH3?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.field = {single: 'untitled'};
    $scope.addNew_SingleField = function (index) {
        var singlehtml = '<fieldset id="single_field" ng-click="selectSingle($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.single"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="{{field.single}}"><button ng-click="removeSingle($index)">-</button></fieldset>';
        var single = $compile(singlehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(single);
    };
    $scope.removeSingle = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#single_field'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectSingle = function (index) {
        $scope.showSingle_Fieldsettings = true;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="addNew_SingleField($index)">Single Line Text</button>
 <div id="drop"></div>

 <form ng-show="showSingle_Fieldsettings">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.single" class="fieldLabel">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did not get you. Can you explain more?

Comment: how to change appended label each name seperately..

Comment: just check my plunkr code, where if we click singlefield button then fields will append down, if we click any field of appended value it shows filed label option, i have to change that appended field label each name seperately from shown filed label option .. can u pls help me

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding a new field, you're binding `field.single` to it. And in the input field where you update the field title, you're updating `field.single` so all the fields will have the same value. What you want is to have an array instead of just a variable. Like `field.single[0], field.single[1]` etc and update each accordingly.

Comment: thank you jianweichuah. i did change using field.single[i] in append values it is changing, but in field label option how it will catch the exact field label value.. can u pls deeply explain me ?

Comment: **see  here once pleace** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734801/how-to-change-each-appended-text-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions,

1. Do not change the DOM (you are doing this in method `addNew_SingleField`). Make sure you write your code in such a way that when ever there is a chnage in data then the DOM should update itself with new data changes.
2. Removing or Deleting element (refer `removeSingle`). This can be done by simply deleting the data in the model which will update view in angular way.
3. You are using the same `field.single` to all the labels which will eventually give us the same name to all the labels. Get the names from an array. In the below case I have given label names based on the index values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {

      $scope.count = 0;

      $scope.items = [];


      $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.items.push({
          'name': $scope.count,
          'value': 'enter ' + $scope.count + ' value'
        });
        $scope.count++;
      };

      $scope.delete = function(index) {
        // console.log(index);
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
  <button ng-click="click()">Single Line Text</button>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
          <td>
            <label>{{item.name}}</label>
            <input type='text' value={{item.value}}>
            <button ng-click='delete($index)'>delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but i need to change the values from append event only, we can get the values using push event and using ng-repeat we can change label names separately. but i have lot of different click events to append different type of fields to append after a single div simultaneously .. pls help me, i'm worrying about this event from so many days..

Comment: @VijjuSena Can you explain this `How can I change each label value from single field label option?` What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: i appended 3 times,, have to change those three label names with different names ...

Comment: @VijjuSena From where do you want to assign the names? What is the source for getting the names? Is it an array if so where is the array declared in your code?

Comment: from field label option i have to assign the names, there by have to change each label names. i'm not getting how to give array for each value, just give me a sample that how to change each name..

Comment: @VijjuSena oops. Until now I haven't clicked on the input box. So when we  click on the input box we get an input field where we enter the name of the respective label right? Le me check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98965/discussion-between-vijju-sena-and-che).

Comment: @VijjuSena Nope. Tried my best but could not. I am having some issues when I change the field from JSON to array of JSON .. it is not working. If you solve it then do post your answer here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734801/how-to-change-each-appended-text-angularjs