# How to Change each Appended text Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm not getting result properly using append event instead of using ng-repeat in adding each name. Can you please help me how can I change added each name from a single input field. Tell me without using ng-repeat in this because ng-repeat functionality is not working to me for my further running functionalities, you can solve this using jquery or javascript if it's possible without using ng-repeat. Thanks in advance..
[Here is JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wexinapole/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
       $scope.add_Name = function (index) {
        var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName($index)">{{my.name}} //click<br/></label>';
        var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    };
   
    $scope.selectName = function (index) {
        $scope.showName = true;
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why don't you write a directive ? and why do you hate [**`ngRepeat`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) ?

Comment: i want to add names in different forms,, if i use ng-repeat, when i wanted to see saved forms to change again it was showing invisible where i click add names it was adding multiple names in a single click.. thats why i'm not going to use **ng-repeat**..

Comment: You are missing a <script> link to your .js file.. that could be causing some issues.

Comment: if i wrote directive, i have to use ng-repeat in that directive template also.. where also i'm facing same issue with [ngRepeat]..

Comment: no i did not miss any script.. the one and only problem is using ng-repeat in div.. if we use ng-repeat, when we reopen the saved form it will be shows invisible,, if we click add name then only it was showing.. can u pls tell me how to solve this issue...???

Comment: @BrianBaker ,  no i did not miss any script.. the one and only problem is using ng-repeat in div.. if we use ng-repeat, when we reopen the saved form it will be shows invisible,, if we click add name then only it was showing.. can u pls tell me how to solve this issue...???

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi
i want to add names in different forms,, if i use ng-repeat, when i wanted to see saved forms to change again it was showing invisible where i click add names it was adding multiple names in a single click.. thats why i'm not going to use ng-repeat..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for correctly this should work.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="add_Name()">Add Names</button>
 <div ng-repeat="item in names">
  <label ng-click="selectName($index)">{{$index}}- {{item}} //click to change<br/></label>        
 </div>

 <form ng-show="showName">
  <label>Name Change at index {{nameIndex}}</label><br/>
  <input ng-model="names[nameIndex]">
 </form>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$scope.names = [];

$scope.add_Name = function(index){
 $scope.names.push('untitled')
}

$scope.selectName = function (index) {
    $scope.nameIndex = index;
    $scope.showName = true;
};
```

Comment: that's fine.. but my requirement is no need to use ng-repeat in div... can u please solve without using ng-repeat,, even in jquery or something.. thnl you

Comment: @Brian you need to change it to `ng-repeat="item in names track by $index"`. There are problems when adding identical names. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1haek2tm/).

Comment: I was hoping that I could convince you to use ng-repeat :)                                @georgeawg.. agreed thanks for catching that.

Comment: Could you add some to my example to show where ng-repeat causes problems? I think it would be best practice to help you solve the problem in an angular way since you're using angular.